# CORS policy 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' (Anguar 8 and Servlet)

Tags: java, angular, servlets, cors

Getting error while making post request from Angular app to servlet doPost method.

Angular application make 2 request 1 for doGet method and other doPost method.

In doGet method i added following heders as follows

```
resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

and solved my CORS problem for GET call.

but doPost method give CORS error even i added same header in doPost method.

angular console shows

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/server/config' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy.Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Server is written in servlet and running on port 8080.
Front end is written in Angular 8 and running on port 4200.

How to solve CORS error for post call...

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

In your code, only allow GET method. Update your code like:

```
resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
But by implementing custom CORS filter problem got solved..

[link](https://howtodoinjava.com/servlets/java-cors-filter-example/)

Comment: Sure. Many method to solve the problem. But the essential is to  "setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE");"